# Visual Studio Microsoft Identity Platform Configuration Stuck Loading

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

I’ve created an asp.net core mvc web app through a visual studio template and selected Microsoft identity platform as an authentication type since i'm trying to connect this to an azure b2c. I have not made any changes to the code, and I’m fully logged in. When the application was successfully created, I configured the Secrets.json dependency, and that worked all fine, but when i tried to configure the Microsoft Identity Platform service dependency, it is stuck loading. I can't select anything and its been loading for over an hour. I've tried restarting my machine and it didn't work.

Any help is appreciated. Thank You!

[image]

Sorry if this is a duplicate, i couldn't find anything like this.

Comment: It seems your account lacks some permission.  Please try to use this account to log in azure portal, and check the app registrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue maybe related to permission. I have some steps you can try to solve it.

**Steps**

1. Use current account to log in azure portal. And try to check whether you can find some app registrations items.
2. If you can, it seems your visual studio have some issue, you can upgrade your visual studio to the latest version.
3. If you can't see the application in azure portal, please contact your administrator, and [let him give you contributor access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I can see the application, but I have to switch directories from default to the auto generated b2c directory. Is it possible that causes the problem?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, I also suspect that there may be a problem with your subscriptions or directories. [You can set default directories in azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJT7Q.png) so you won't have this problem.

Comment: thank you so much! I’ve updated visual studio and set the default directory to the b2c one and it works! Thank you so so much. You’re a legend. :] I’ll upvote your answer once i get enough reputation.